# How can I remove the additional language keyboard in the window10?

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to remove QAA (unknown locale - US keyboard; see below image).However, I don't see it exists in the language settings. Can anyone please suggest the solutin to solve this issue? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this after a quick search.

Launch PowerShell as an Administrator, then type the following:

```
$LanguageList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$LanguageList.Add("qaa-latn")
Set-WinUserLanguageList $LanguageList -Force
```

Then it should come up in Windows Settings and you can remove it from there.